# PyQt5 SystemTrayIcon's Context Menu doesn't accept key strokes when triggered programmatically

Tags: python, pyqt5, archlinux, dbus

I have a python script that uses PyQt5 to place a system Tray Icon, which I can use to run other scripts.

It's excellent for multiple scripts handling, and since I don't use them often there is no point assigning keyboard shortcuts for all of those scripts.

As long as I use the right-click to open the context menu, it's fine, but I'd also like to trigger it from keystrokes. The problem I faced is when I don't click at the Icon, even if the menu is shown the focus is not there so any other keystrokes don't reach there.

The part to trigger the context menu is:

```py
    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(QDBusMessage)
    def dmsg(self, message):
        menu = self.icon.contextMenu()
        if menu.isVisible():
            menu.close()
        else:
            menu.exec(QtCore.QPoint(0,0))
            # menu.show()
```

I can use the dbus to send a signal which triggers this function and the ContextMenu can be seen without having to click the system tray Icon.

I use `dbus-send --system / gaurav.menu.toggle` to send the signal to toggle the context menu visibility, and it works.

A reproducible example is as follows:

```py
from PyQt5 import QtGui, QtWidgets, QtCore
from PyQt5.QtDBus import QDBusConnection, QDBusMessage
import sys

def exe_script(name):
    action = name.text()
    if action == '&Exit':
        sys.exit(0)
    elif action == '&Hello':
        print('hello')

def read_actions():
    return 

def get_menu(all_actions):
    menu = QtWidgets.QMenu()
    actions = []
    for name in ['&Exit', '&Hello']:
        mi = menu.addAction(name)
        actions.append(mi)
    menu.triggered.connect(lambda q:exe_script(q))
    return menu,actions



class QDBhandler(QtCore.QObject):
    def __init__(self,icon):
        super(QDBhandler,self).__init__()
        bus = QDBusConnection.systemBus()
        bus.registerObject('/', self)
        bus.connect(
            '',
            '/',
            'gaurav.menu',
            'toggle',
            self.dmsg
        )
        self.icon = icon

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(QDBusMessage)
    def dmsg(self, message):
        menu = self.icon.contextMenu()
        if menu.isVisible():
            menu.close()
        else:
            menu.exec(QtCore.QPoint(0,0))
            # menu.show()
        

def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    icon = QtWidgets.QSystemTrayIcon()
    handler = QDBhandler(icon)
    icon.setToolTip('Execute Scripts')
    actions_dict = read_actions()
    menu,actions = get_menu(actions_dict)
    icon.setContextMenu(menu)
    icon.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

System Information:
Archlinux, i3-gaps window manager

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem when running the dbus command, but I faced a similar issue previously when using a keyboard shortcut, and it has to do with the window manager keyboard focus management: sometimes the menu doesn't get the focus properly (usually if it appears when the key has not been released yet, and the previous X object is still "grabbing" the keyboard). It seems that Qt circumvents that internally by releasing the focus when triggered with the `Context` reason, but as of now I'm still unable to avoid that 100%.

Comment: When you run this and send that dbus trigger it works on yours (like send dbus signal then press E for exit.)? As you said my keys are grabbed by whatever window I was on before sending that dbus signal. 
Is there a way to trigger that Context myself? I tried to call the trigger with Reason, but it won't let me call it.

Comment: Unfortunately, the trigger signal is emitted internally using the (private) system platform helper, calling it manually won't help you. The are only two alternative I know of, and neither of them are actually very good: go in deep into the X bindings in order to "clear" the current keyboard grabber, or create a fake mouse click event (using QTest or an external tool) in order to emulate the mouse button.

Comment: Well, if I really have to go that far, it's better to make a widget/window instead of context menu. That way it'll definitely get focus when it runs. I should probably use xlib/sdl2 to make it in C so that it'll be faster and consume less memory. I thought it'd have a simple solution and it'd be easier to modify something if done in python.

Comment: It technically is simple, the problem comes when dealing with some system related issues like these (technically it is "not" Qt's fault, but it's due to the way the wm behaves and how Qt creates new widgets). Note that with PyGtk this is feasible, as it provides global shortcuts (which are not available on Qt) using the keybinder module, and keyboard focus is correctly grabbed on popup.